# How can I validate the date of birth once the user clicks in another form group?

Tags: javascript

Please see the code below:

```
 <div class="form-group" onblur="ValidateDateOfBirth()">
                <label class="control-label" style="width: 30%;">
                    Date of Birth
                </label>
                <input asp-for="DayOfBirth" style="width: 10%;" class="form-control" />
                <input asp-for="MonthOfBirth" style="width: 10%;" class="form-control" />
                <input asp-for="YearOfBirth" style="width: 10%;" class="form-control" />
            </div>
```

I expect the date of birth to be validated when the user moves away from the three textboxes (form group), however nothing happens.  If I change the event from onBlur to onChange then the date of birth is validated if any of the values within the three textboxes change.

How can I validate the date of birth once the user clicks in another form group?

Comment: @DavidG, I have edited the tags.  However, I believe it is relevant to asp.net core (because onblur seems to work outside o9f asp.net core).

Comment: It is not. @DavidG is correct. This is pure JavaScript and any answer would be equally applicable if you were using ASP.NET Core or Spring or Django or Ruby on Rails, etc.

Comment: @Chris Pratt, ok thanks for clarifying that.  I have edited the tags to JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A div does not trigger a `blur` event. Ever. That's just basic EMCAScript spec stuff. The `blur` event will only be triggered by the individual inputs. Since your problem boils down to needing to wait until all three fields are completed before triggering the validation, then you'll need to check if the three inputs are "dirty" or not. In other words, add the onblur validation to each input. Then, in your validation method:

```
// get values of day, month, and year inputs
if (day.trim() !== '' && month.trim() !== '' && year.trim() !== '') {
    // run validation
}
```

Comment: But if the user moves from day to month then that is acceptable because they have not completed filling in the date yet.  +1 for the reference to DIV.

Comment: @w0051977 Then you need to change the logic to handle blank entries for month and year.

Comment: Yes. I understand that. That's the point of the code above. You still *call* the validation method because it might need to be validated, but the conditional causes the validation to be skipped if all the fields aren't ready yet.

Comment: I was hoping to also cater for the scenario where they fill in an incomplete date and continue down the form.  I believe your code would not identify this as a validation error.

Comment: No, but again, that's simply another condition. You could for example check the focus within the validation method and if it's not on one of these inputs, then you can generically invalidate it as incomplete.